# Accepted an answer message

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, top-bar, achievements-dialog

When you accept an answer on one of your questions, you get 2 reputation for it. The achievements dropdown tells you with a shiny green +2 on the topbar, and shows this:

[image: +2 What affects the change to get ambushed on Framing Frame Day 2?]

Why did I get +2 for it again?

It would be better if the message told you it was because you accepted an answer, right there in the dropdown, without the need to go into your profile to see more details.

Comment: But what if you also get upvote on the question? Then you will see +7. Adding tooltip sounds reasonable though, +1.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Good point. This needs some more thought. Maybe some description when you hover over it in the style of "2 upvotes, 1 downvote, edit, accepted answer" and omit the unnecessary ones.